# Bose-Einstein condensation transition line

Tags: bose-einstein-condensate

I'm having some trouble figuring out the formula for the transition line for a BEC, i.e. the function $P(v)$, where $P$ is the pressure and $v$ is the volume of the BEC.  I've substituted
$$k_BT_c=\frac{2\pi\hbar^2}{m}\left(\frac{n}{g_{3/2}(1)}\right)^{2/3}$$
and
$$v_c=\frac{\lambda_T^3}{g_{3/2}(1)}$$
into the expression for pressure, which is
$$P=\frac{k_BT}{\lambda_T^3}g_{5/2}(1)$$
but this doesn't give me the expected solution, which is
$$Pv^{5/3}=\frac{2\pi\hbar^2m\cdot g_{5/2}(1)}{(g_{3/2}(1))^{5/3}}$$
The main issue I keep running into is how to cancel out the number density of the BEC $n$.  I've tried using $n=1/v$, which gives the right power for $v$, but doesn't move the mass to the numerator.  Where have I gone wrong or missed something?